# Open sharepoint page already logged in from WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, sharepoint

I have a WPF application that scans a user's fingerprint. From it, it obtains the user's Sharepoint login and password. My issue is in how am I supposed to be able to 1) Open a Sharepoint page in a web browser and 2) The user must not have to enter his credentials again. How can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, even if people think this question isn't worth it, I am posting this so others can use this. What I did was parse through the input objects on the page in a WebBrowser and manipulate them like so:

```
foreach (mshtml.IHTMLElement element in inputs)
{
    if (element.getAttribute("Name").Contains("UserName"))
    {
        hayUsername = true;
        element.setAttribute("value", usr);
    }

    if (element.getAttribute("Name").Contains("password"))
    {
        hayPass = true;
            element.setAttribute("value", pas);
    }       
}

foreach (mshtml.IHTMLElement element in inputs)
{

    if (element.getAttribute("Name").Contains("login"))
    {
        element.click();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps somebody else.